# Netty HTTP/3 codec dependency giving an error in Gradle

Tags: gradle, netty, quic, http3

I'm currently working on implementing HTTP3 server using the Gradle version 7.3 on a Ubuntu 20.04 VM. But QUIC codec (0.0.20.Final) and HTTP/3 codec (0.0.11.Final) dependencies produce the following error.

```
   Could not find netty-incubator-codec-native-quic-0.0.25.Final-${os.detected.name}-${os.detected.arch}.jar (io.netty.incubator:netty-incubator-codec-native-quic:0.0.25.Final).

Possible solution:
 - Declare repository providing the artifact, see the documentation at https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/declaring_repositories.html
```

Following are the dependencies I used

```
implementation 'io.netty.incubator:netty-incubator-codec-quic:0.0.20.Final:linux-x86_64'
implementation 'io.netty.incubator:netty-incubator-codec-http3:0.0.11.Final'
```

Comment: did you find a solution to this? I have the same issue.
I was able to make it work with maven (pom.xml)
`<dependency>
            <groupId>io.netty.incubator</groupId>
            <artifactId>netty-incubator-codec-quic</artifactId>
            <version>0.0.20.Final</version>
            <classifier>linux-x86_64</classifier>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.netty.incubator</groupId>
            <artifactId>netty-incubator-codec-http3</artifactId>
            <version>0.0.11.Final</version>
        </dependency>`

Comment: No still didn’t find anything.  And yeah worked with maven for me too.

Answer (score 0):

As a temporary solution I downloaded the jar of the dependency from [here](https://jarcasting.com/artifacts/io.netty.incubator/netty-incubator-codec-http3/) and referenced it in the build.gradle file.

```
implementation ("io.netty.incubator:netty-incubator-codec-quic:0.0.20.Final:linux-x86_64")
implementation (files("libs/netty-incubator-codec-http3-0.0.11.Final.jar"))
```

Comment: Yeah that's how I’m using for now. But need to find a way to work with the dependencies

Answer (score 0):

Gradle is struggling to parse the classifier for the quic dependency, which is a property defined in terms of other properties, which are meant to be detected at build-time.

To work around that, *exclude* the quic dependency from your http3 dependency, and instead pull in quic directly:

```java
implementation ( "io.netty.incubator:netty-incubator-codec-http3:0.0.11.Final" ) {
    exclude group: "io.netty.incubator"
}
implementation "io.netty.incubator:netty-incubator-codec-native-quic:0.0.27.Final"
runtimeOnly ( group: "io.netty.incubator", name: "netty-incubator-codec-native-quic", classifier: "osx-x86_64" )
runtimeOnly ( group: "io.netty.incubator", name: "netty-incubator-codec-native-quic", classifier: "linux-x86_64" )
```